# The sum of $n$ terms in $1 \cdot 2+2 \cdot 3+3 \cdot 4+\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recreational-mathematics

I am just confused, considering we can take $1 \cdot 2$ as the first term then we get the $n$th term as $n(n+1)$ so the sum of $n$ terms would be $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ + $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ but let's assume $0 \cdot 1$ as the first term then the $n$th term becomes $(n-1) \cdot n$ and so it's summation becomes $\frac{n(n+1) (2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ but it's the same summation as above but the results are different what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You sum up until $(n-1)\cdot n$  in the second case, not until $n(n+1)$

Comment: In the second case, you have to sum up to $n(n+1)$ and in the second case you sum up to $(n-1)n$. You need to add the missing term $n(n+1)$ in the second case, which resolves the apparent contradiction.

Comment: You may also be interested in the so called *hockey stick identity*. Apart from a factor of two, the summands are binomial coefficients $\binom{n+1}2$. Staring at the Pascal triangle (moving $\binom22$ to $\binom 33$) gives you a binomial coefficient on the third diagonal as the sum :-)

Answer (score 7):

The results are same.

The first $n$ terms of first series is different from first $n$ terms of second series. Thus, You'll get different answers if you plug in same $n$ . In fact, you'll have to plug $n+1$ terms in second to get same as that of $n$ terms of first.

Answer (score 2):

This reduces the problem to the evaluation of a second derivative.
$$
   1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3+ 3\cdot 4+ \cdots + n\cdot (n+1)
   = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k+1) \\
   = \left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n+1})\right|_{x=1} \\
   = \left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}\right|_{x=1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$S_1=1⋅2+2⋅3+3⋅4+\dots$
$T_n=n(n+1)$
$S_1=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bf+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$S_2=1⋅2+2⋅3+3⋅4+\dots$
$T_n=(n-1)n$
$S_2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bf-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

As the bold part indicates, the summation **isn't** the same.

Let's put $\bf n=1$:
$S_1=1⋅2=2$
$S_1=\frac{1(2)(3)}{6}\bf+\frac{1(2)}{2}=1+1=2$

$S_2=0⋅1=0$
$S_2=\frac{1(2)(3)}{6}\bf-\frac{1(2)}{2}=1-1=0$

Let's put $\bf n=1$:
$S_1=1⋅2+2⋅3=8$
$S_1=\frac{2(3)(5)}{6}\bf+\frac{2(3)}{2}=5+3=8$

$S_2=0⋅1+1⋅2=2$
$S_2=\frac{2(3)(5)}{6}\bf-\frac{2(3)}{2}=5-3=2$

So, what you have done is totally correct and verifies.
Whenever there is confusion like such that you have, working out for small values of $n$ which we can ourselves calculate helps to make things clearer.

Comment: This answers highlights that the two summations are different, but not what the difference is. Also, your chosen notation adds to the confusion. You gave the same name to two different definitions of $T_n$, and didn't make the dependence of $S_1$ and $S_2$ on $n$ explicit. This makes it hard to highlight the difference. The difference is just that one of the two sequences is shifted by one term., and $S_2(n+1) = S_1(n)$, or alternatively $S_2(n) = S_1(n) + T_n$.

Answer (score 0):

In first case. ${\color{green}S_n}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}={\color{red}{\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}}}$
In second case, $S'_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}={\color{red}{\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}}}={\color{green}S_n}$